# Vue|Nuxt - Copy project to production server leads to error

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

### What I did:

- deleted local `node_modules` folder
- Copied it to our production server
- ran `npm install`
- ran `npm run dev`

### What I expected:

Application to start and run like on my developer workstation

### What happened:

Application throws an error: `Cannot read property 'props' of undefined`

### Screenshots:

- http://prntscr.com/rnajmw
- http://prntscr.com/rnc4q9

> You might want to add your code and terminal output here

Comment: Hi Viacheslav, great to have you here. May I suggest you update your question a little bit. For code we don't use screen shots, but copy and paste it. Put ``` on the line before and after the code and it will format nicely. I updated the text, hope you are OK with it

Answer (score 0):

remove package-lock.json file and try again 'npm install'.Thanks

Comment: Same error ERROR  `[Vue warn]: Invalid component name: "_6f6c098b". Component names should conform to valid custom element name in html5 specification.`

Comment: `const _6f6c098b = () => import('..\\layouts\\default.vue'  /* webpackChunkName: "layouts_default" */).then(m => m.default || m)
const _103c6d61 = () => import('..\\layouts\\landing.vue'  /* webpackChunkName: "layouts_landing" */).then(m => m.default || m)
const _82e1354c = () => import('..\\layouts\\testing.vue'  /* webpackChunkName: "layouts_testing" */).then(m => m.default || m)
const layouts = { "_default": sanitizeComponent(_6f6c098b),"_landing": sanitizeComponent(_103c6d61),"_testing": sanitizeComponent(_82e1354c) }

let resolvedLayouts = {}
export default {
  render (h, props) {`

Answer (score 0):

splitChunks.layouts must be **false**.

nuxt.config.js

```
 splitChunks: {
      layouts: false, // in my case, it was true
      pages: true,
    },
```